# How to append a timestamp after a copyTo has been executed on an onEdit trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-apps

I'm using an onEdit function to trigger (among other things) a copyTo that moves a single row (consisting of two columns) to a new sheet (called CAC). Unrelated, the onEdit trigger is also adding a timestamp to a different sheet. I can't figure out how to add another timestamp to the CAC sheet in the column to the right of where the copyTo is landing. I'm assuming it's a combination of an offset and nesting something within the copyTo, but after some time of trying, can't figure it out! Thank you!

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // DUE TODAY 

{
  e.source.toast('Processing...');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(name=='Posting Tasks' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value) {
    e.source.toast('Processing...');
    var id=e.range.offset(0,2).getValue();
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Database');
    var idA=tsh.getRange(3,2,tsh.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
    var row=idA.indexOf(id)+3;
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Database').getRange(row,11).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  }

  // Copy to CAC

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  if(ss.getActiveSheet() === 'Posting Tasks'){
        //Get active cell
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var cellCol = cell.getColumn();
    var cellRow = cell.getRow(); 
    var exportRange = sheet.getRange(cellRow,2,1,6);
        //Select the paste destination
    var pasteDestination = ss.getSheetByName('CAC');
    var pasteEmptyBottomRow = pasteDestination.getLastRow() + 1;

        //Copy the row to the new destination
    exportRange.copyTo(pasteDestination.getRange(pasteEmptyBottomRow,3),
                       SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);

        // add timestamp

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put the timestamp to the right column of the column of the values copied by `exportRange.copyTo(pasteDestination.getRange(pasteEmptyBottomRow,3), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES)`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this modification, I used `offset()`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
exportRange.copyTo(pasteDestination.getRange(pasteEmptyBottomRow,3),
                   SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
```

To:

```
var timestamp = new Date();
var destRange = pasteDestination.getRange(pasteEmptyBottomRow,3);
exportRange.copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
destRange.offset(0, exportRange.getNumColumns() - 1, exportRange.getNumRows()).setValue(timestamp);
```

- When you run the modified script, the timestamp is put to the cells of the right column of the copied values.

#### Note:

- If you want to put the timestamp to only one cell, please modify `destRange.offset(0, exportRange.getNumColumns() - 1, exportRange.getNumRows()).setValue(timestamp);` to `destRange.offset(0, exportRange.getNumColumns() - 1).setValue(timestamp);`.
- In this case, as a sample, `new Date()` is used as the timestamp. So the date is put as the date object to the cell. If you want to see the time, please set the format of the cells with the date object.

#### Reference:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: thanks for the edits. Tried to update and although the copyTo still works, there's no timestamp appearing. Here's the original sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XWr6RUa3gpXfAQ88Snw7WIqDcou4ZOIAd9a6sOvsRMA/edit?usp=sharing  Any thoughts? @Tanaike

Comment: @Andrew Karp Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I had thought that your script worked except for adding the timestamp. From your script, I noticed that `if(ss.getActiveSheet() === 'Posting Tasks'){` is not correct. Please modify to `if(ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() === 'Posting Tasks'){`. And in your case, `destRange.offset(0, exportRange.getNumColumns()).setValue(timestamp);` might be suitable. How about this? If that was not the result you want, can you explain about your goal? Because from your shared Spreadsheet, I cannot understand about it.

Comment: Update: it worked! The original copy script was missing a few components, but once that was all added back in original format, your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew Karp Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.